# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) when trying to read from a json file

Tags: python, json, deep-learning, nltk

I am trying to read from my intents.json file as below but I am getting a json decodeError as above (in the title) for the following code, can anyone please help me out:
My main.py file:

```
import nltk
from nltk.stem.lancaster import LancasterStemmer
import random
import json
import tensorflow
import tflearn
import numpy
stemmer = LancasterStemmer()
with open("intents.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

print(data["intents"])
```

My intents.json file:

```
{"intents": [
    {"tag": "greeting",
     "patterns": ["Hi", "How are you", "Is anyone there?", "Hello", "Good day", "Whats up"],
     "responses": ["Hello!", "Good to see you again!", "Hi there, how can I help?"],
     "context_set": ""
    },
    {"tag": "goodbye",
     "patterns": ["cya", "See you later", "Goodbye", "I am Leaving", "Have a Good day"],
     "responses": ["Sad to see you go :(", "Talk to you later", "Goodbye!"],
     "context_set": ""
    },
    {"tag": "age",
     "patterns": ["how old", "how old is tim", "what is your age", "how old are you", "age?"],
     "responses": ["I am 18 years old!", "18 years young!"],
     "context_set": ""
    },
    {"tag": "name",
     "patterns": ["what is your name", "what should I call you", "whats your name?"],
     "responses": ["You can call me Tim.", "I'm Tim!", "I'm Tim aka Tech With Tim."],
     "context_set": ""
    },
    {"tag": "shop",
     "patterns": ["Id like to buy something", "whats on the menu", "what do you reccommend?", "could i get something to eat"],
     "responses": ["We sell chocolate chip cookies for $2!", "Cookies are on the menu!"],
     "context_set": ""
    },
    {"tag": "hours",
     "patterns": ["when are you guys open", "what are your hours", "hours of operation"],
     "responses": ["We are open 7am-4pm Monday-Friday!"],
     "context_set": ""
    }
]
}
```

Comment: The error `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)` is a hint for a empty file. As you only give a relative path, chances are that you are not processing the expected file. Please twice control your current directory.

Answer (score 1):

hey are you sure that your code aren`t working? i copied your code and its work perfectly check this screenshot -> [image]